# "Behavioral type system" and can it be done with Akka?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

The following paper [Model-Driven Development - From Object-Oriented Design to Actor-Oriented Design 2003](http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/publications/papers/03/MontereyWorkshopLee/MontereyWorkshopLee.pdf) indicates that it is possible to compose actors if "behavioral type system" is defined. Which, I gather, is like a behavioral-interface between actors.

Is there such a thing in Akka? Could it be defined?